# Бот вк оправлет сообщение через некоторое время повторно

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть бот в вк, я уже сталкивался с этой проблемой и мне говорили брать random_id, но так как этот бот должен работать и в беседе и в лс прикрепить его к id сообщениюя не выйдет. И так вот код :

```
function vk_msg_send($peer_id,$text,$id){
$request_params = array(
'random_id'=>$id,
'message' => $text, 
'peer_id' => $peer_id, 
'access_token' => "token",
'v' => '5.87' 
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}
switch ($data->type) {
    case 'confirmation': 
        echo $confirmation_token; 

    break;  
    case 'message_new':
    $message_text = $data -> object -> text;
        $id_user = $data -> object -> peer_id;
        $id_user2 = $data -> object -> from_id;
        $mess_id=$data -> object -> conversation_message_id;
vk_msg_send($id_user,"text",$mess_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю бот работает через Callback API?
Если так, то в документации есть такая строка:

> Обратите внимание: после получения уведомления Ваш сервер должен возвращать строку "ok" и статус HTTP 200. Если сервер несколько раз подряд вернет ошибку,
> Callback API временно перестанет отправлять на него уведомления.

Попробуйте добавить в конце скрипта

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo 'OK';
```

(Нужно чтоб на страницу не выводилось ничего кроме OK)